# Using an html form, I'm trying to send a calculated field to php file

Tags: php, forms, field

I see reference to using hidden fields for this, but can't get the calculated value into the value field.
User inputs a $ amount and a quantity. I want to calculate the total amount and send that to the php file.

```
Item Amount:<input name="amt" id="amt" onchange="myfunction()">
Quantity:<input type=number id="qty" name="qty" onchange="myfunction()">
Total Amount:<input readonly id="total" name="total" value=??? here I want 
to fill with total calculated in myfunction.>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var total = document.getElementById("qty").value * 
document.getElementById("amt").value ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to try yourself first, then come here with a specific issue or problem. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't help you if we can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an input field for the total amount. Calculate and fill its value with Javascript. Don't forget to put this field inside a form tag. On submission of the form, you can access its value through PHP.

Comment: I have the input field for the total amount. I just don't know how to fill its value. I have added my code above.

Comment: `document.getElementById('total').value= total`

Comment: It's far more easier with jQuery.
`$('#total').val(total);`

Comment: Thanks. I had found the first answer above on another post. It works great and so easy to add.

Comment: If you have found this answer helpful, do upvote and mark it as accepted. Helps me build my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Create a input hidden tag and assign calculated total and through name of that tag , you can access it in php server